# Placing default components in an iParsys

Tags: templates, components, aem

We have a default set of header and footer components that we want to display on every page.

In my template files, I have lines like the following to include components automatically:

```
<cq:include path="thecomponent" resourceType="/path/to/component"  />
```

However, the options for the components are not inherited down to child pages, so our users would need to rebuild their headers and footers every time they make a new page. In my template file, is there a way to place these components in an iParsys automatically?

This attempt was not successful, but I think it illustrates what I want to do:

```
<cq:include path="PageTop" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/iparsys">   
    <cq:include path="thecomponent" resourceType="/path/to/component"  />  
    <cq:include path="theOthercomponent" resourceType="/path/to/other/component"  />
</cq:include>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same situation & I found this work-round solution.

Set `cq:noDecoration` to `false` against your components (header & footer ) which you want something like this

```
<cq:include path="PageTop" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/iparsys">   
    <cq:include path="thecomponent" resourceType="/path/to/component"  />  
    <cq:include path="theOthercomponent" resourceType="/path/to/other/component"  />
</cq:include>
```

Now to change `cq:noDecoration` values to `true` dynamically you have to include this code in your component's jsp file ( header & footer ).

```
<%
    String defaultCanonicalURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    String[] template = defaultCanonicalURL.split("/");
    String templateName = template[template.length-2].toString(); // getting template name


    if(templateName.equals("your-desired-template-name")){
        componentContext.setDecorate(true);    
    }
%>
```

Hope it helps .

http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/components.html for reference.

Answer (score 0):

[`HierarchyNodeInheritanceValueMap`](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/inherit/HierarchyNodeInheritanceValueMap.html) seems to be right solution here. In your header/footer component JSPs you may use it like that:

```
<%
    HierarchyNodeInheritanceValueMap map;
    map = new HierarchyNodeInheritanceValueMap(resource);
%>
...
some inherited property: <%= map.getInherited("myProperty", "") %><br/>
other inherited property: <%= map.getInherited("otherProperty", "") %>
```

It will try to get `myProperty` and `otherProperty` from the current resource and if they don't exist, appropriate resources from the ancestor pages will be used. More info can be found in the [class Javadoc](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/inherit/HierarchyNodeInheritanceValueMap.html).